# JAVA IF Else variables

Tags: java

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    String employeeInput;
    String assetInput;

    String userInput = txtUserInput.getText();
    userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

    if (userInput.startsWith("emp")){

        //String employeeInput = null;
        employeeInput = userInput.replaceAll("\\s","");
        txtUserInput.setText("");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The Scan was " );

    }else if (userInput.startsWith("u")){

        assetInput = userInput;
        assetInput.replaceAll("\\s","");
        txtUserInput.setText("");


        System.out.println("Employee ID is " + **employeeInput**); //asks for employeeInput to be declared.

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The Scan was " + assetInput);
```

I want the employeeInput to be filled and saved, untill it is replaced by another employeeInput. The problem I'm having is when getting the item input, the employeeInput is now missing. What is the way to do this?

Thank you, for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`employeeInput` is a method variable, so everytime you exit the method you will lose the reference to it.

The obvious thing to try is turn `employeeInput` into a member variable. Just declare it at the top of your class.

Better yet may be to persist that value to a database.

Comment: Dear lord I'm border line mentally challenged I swear. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know that the first condition has already been met. Nor, do I. But, you could change

```
String employeeInput; // <-- may not have been initialized
```

to a default value (possibly even explicitly `null`), here the empty `String` `""`.

```
String employeeInput = "";
```

Comment: Thanks I had set it to null. string employeeInput = null; but when I call upon it in the elseif part it would put the employeeinput back to null instead of the previous scan. :( I'm hopeless. Is there a way to make the employeeInput stay untill it has been inputed a second time? instead of whipped back to null or "" each time?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your `employeeInput` variable is 'missing' or could be removed after any other variable is set. So its most likely you aren't initializing your variables when they're defined.

Try initializing them like

```
String employeeInput = ""; // or = null
String assetInput = ""; // or = null
String userInput = txtUserInput.getText().toLowerCase();
```

And your problem should be solved. The compiler might also be giving you a warning about this.

You might also want to try removing this `txtUserInput.setText("");` line to test for problems.

Edit:

If you are trying to access this variable after your method has finished executing then it will be wiped so instead of putting it in your method declare it in your class like `public class Name{
    public /*static*/ String employeeInput = ""; //or null
}`